# Meteor publish records before and after user login

Tags: meteor

My publish function is like this:

```
    Meteor.publish('ownedrecords', function() {
        if (!this.userId) {
            this.error(new Meteor.Error(500, 'Internal server error'));
            return;
        }
        return Records.find({owner:this.userId});
    });
```

I subscribe in the client like this:

```
    Meteor.subscribe("ownedrecords")
```

But after the user logs-in the client does not get the records owned by the user. So I did this:

```
    Deps.autorun(function() {
            var user = Meteor.userId();
            Meteor.subscribe("ownedrecords");
    }
```

This solved the problem. But is this a standard and recommended practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current/Active subscriptions will automatically re-run when the user logs in or out.

The convention is then to call `this.ready()` in situations where you want this to occur:

```
Meteor.publish('ownedrecords', function() {
    if (!this.userId) {
        this.ready();
        return;
    }
    return Records.find({owner:this.userId});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You're throwing an Error if the user is not logged in:

Because of this the client will abort the subscription and so when the user is logged in they wont get the updates anymore as the subscription is no longer active.

All you need to do is avoid throwing an error.

```
Meteor.publish('ownedrecords', function() {
    if (!this.userId) return [];

    return Records.find({owner:this.userId});
});
```

If you return an empty cursor or fire `this.ready()` then you should be fine.

Comment: Is it not better (for memory management) to return `this.stop()`? This way the publication does not get created and the server frees up memory. If you return `[]` or `this.ready()` then there is a publication (with no data) which consumes some memory. Am I wrong?

Comment: `this.stop()` would definitely save memory since it closes the subscription off, the observers would still use memory even if the published cursor is empty. My understanding is the OP wants the subscription to return the new relevant data as soon as the user logs in without the `Deps.autorun` so it needs to remain active.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused. Since the userId is coming from a reactive context, once userId is set, would it not actually make the publication active again?

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy the subscription is re-run when the user logs in, but only if it is still active at the time, this is the reason a variation of `this.ready()` has to be sent down. If `this.stop()` or throwing an error is used then the server will have discarded it and its cursors so it wouldn't be run again when the user logs in

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting

```
Meteor.publish('ownedrecords', function() {
  return Records.find({owner:this.userId});
});
```

should result in correct behavior if no documents have `null` owners.